# What type of database design do I use for a questionnaire that has a lot of questions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design

I have a project where I need to record answers to a questionnaire that has 50+ questions. Each question is associated with numbers 1 to 5. So the data for each questionnaire filled out is something like

```
Username : "Bob", 
"Question 1" : 1, 
"Question 2" : 1, 
"Question 3" : 5, 
.
.
.
"Question N" : 2
```

where the same questions are asked for each person. I'm wondering what is the correct database design for this type of situation. Do I make a table like

```
                      Questionaire_Answers
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
       userid    |  Quesiton_1_Answer   |    ....   | Question_N_Answer
```

or what is the better way of doing this? Do I serialize the information with a giant varchar column like

```
        Questionaire_Answers
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
      userid    |                    Question_Answers
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
       1238     | "Question1->1,Question2->1,Question3->5,...QuestionN->2"
```

or what should I  do?

Comment: Neither of those designs are correct. The correct database design could be.... just use SurveyMonkey.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Does Survey Monkey have a way of assigning individual users names and passwords per survey and so forth? I was going to make this in ASP.NET since it needs to be very customized over time.

Comment: It does but you probably have to pay for it. Consider what is the best use of your time - custom writing this, maintaining it and hosting it somewhere.. you still have to write the report out the other side. Or paying Survey Monkey (I don't work for them, I just think people custom build things when they don't need to!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is: "No, you do not serialize the information into a giant `varchar()` column." That is easy, because such serialization is almost never the right thing to do in SQL. The right thing is a junction table.

However, apart from that, a data structure for surveys is quite hard to implement because:

- Questions can be added and removed from a survey, particularly on-line surveys.
- Individual questions can have different versions and the nuances are important.
- Answers can be added and removed for a given question.
- Individual answers can have different versions and the nuances are important.

This is particularly true of on-line surveys, where data is gathered over multiple days. Early responses can lead to changes in the survey -- and for good reasons.

Answer (score 2):

```
UserID     QuestionID     Answer
--------------------------------
1238       1              2 
1238       2              5 
... 
1238       50             3
```

Comment: Won't that table be way larger than the others?

Comment: What do you mean by large?. 100 users x 50 questions x 10 attempts = 50,000 records which is still not 'large'. Not only that it will be far faster and reliable to store it this way. What happens when you want 51 or 49 questions? it's a simple data change not a column change.

Answer (score 1):

I would create three tables for:

1. Questions
2. Choices
3. User Answers

---

```
CREATE TABLE Question(
    QuestionId  INT,
    --Additional Columns
)

CREATE TABLE QuestionAnswer(
    AnswerId    INT,
    QuestionId  INT, --FK to Question
    --AdditionalColumns
)

CREATE TABLE UserAnswer(
    UserId      INT,
    QuestionId  INT,
    AsnwerId    INT
)
```

This way, you have to flexibility to have any number of available choices for each question.

---

> Do I serialize the information with a giant varchar

NO, do not do this. This is a bad design and you'll have to generate complex queries for simple operations. The best way is to normalize your design and use junction tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you are putting this in a sql database, then I would be inclined to create a table like this:

```
userid int
questionid int
answer int
```

So if a particular user answered 50 questions, there would be 50 rows in the table for that user.

If you were using a NoSQL database it would be different, but with TSQL and this design, if your survey changes from 50 to 51 questions you don't need to modify the structure of the database.